# iOS UIScrollView gets stuck and unresponsive with NSRunLoopCommonModes

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, nsrunloop

In my iPhone app I'm using a 3rd party library (libPusher) for WebSockets networking and this library causes every UIScrollView component in my app to become unresponsive. This includes UIScrollViews and UITableView.

What happens is that if a user scrolls one of the UIScrollView components with his finger and happens to keep touching and sliding the view with his finger at the same time that a network operation is under way, then this leads to a completely unresponsive UIScrollView that stops accepting touch events (it thinks that it's in a drag mode all the time even when the finger is lift) and does not decelerate appropriately.  The only way out is to destroy the UIScrollView and recreate a new one.

I have contacted the developer of the library but unfortunately so far haven't heard back.

From what I read, this is a common problem when running a run-loop in an un-appropriate mode such as `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`, however this library *seems* to be doing the right thing and it runs its run loop in `NSRunLoopCommonModes` so I'm unclear as what the right solution is.

I tried playing with different modes (tried `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`) but the behavior is the same.

I'm using iOS 5 and it's the same behavior on the simulator as well as on devices.

Let me paste the code which I think is problematic in the lib and hopefully that'd be enough scope to let you help me find a solution.

In a subclass of NSOperation we have:

```
- (void)start 
{
  NSAssert(URLRequest, @"Cannot start URLRequestOperation without a NSURLRequest.");

  [self setExecuting:YES];

  URLConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:URLRequest delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

  if (URLConnection == nil) {
    [self setFinished:YES]; 
  }

  // Common modes instead of default so it won't stall uiscrollview scrolling
  [URLConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
  [URLConnection start];

  do {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
  } while (!_isFinished);
}
```

This operation runs on the *main* thread, as in `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:authOperation];`. (maybe this is the problem, but I tried running it in another thread and it crashes so the library will need more work to make it background-thread safe so I can't prove yet that this is the solution...)

So far I tried

- changing the run loop mode to `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` - didn't help.
- running the operation in a new operation queue that I created (e.g. not on the main thread) but the library doesn't seem to be ready for this as it crashes.

I still feel like I'm shooting in the dark... help :)

thanks!

Comment: What this library is neccessary for? You could use the standard Foundation types. If not, try creating a different thread for the network operations using pthreads or NSThread.

Comment: The library is a client for the websockets service pusher.com. I'd like to fix the library, but not write a new one from scratch

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but since you're running on the main thread and do run-loop based networking, why are you using an `NSOperation` in the first place?

Comment: it's not my library so I don't know what the author chose to do this in a run loop, could be backwards compatibility or other requirements driven by this module's dependencies. If I wrote it afresh (which I will probably have to...) then I'd use NSOperation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's becoming unresponsive since it's doing a while loop on the main thread. This a bad design pattern.

Since you're on iOS5, why not use NSURLConnection's +sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: ?

If you need to be compatible for iOS4.x I would strip out the run loop stuff and take a look at [this blog post](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/).

Basically, I would do something like this:

```
- (void)start
{
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        return [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(start) 
                                      withObject:nil
                                   waitUntilDone:NO];
    }

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    isExecuting = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    NSURLConnection *aConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                                   delegate:self];

    self.connection = aConnection;
    [aConnection release];

    if (connection == nil) {
        // finish up here
    }
}
```

Comment: To generalize this (for example making a macro, kickToMainThread) you can replace `@selector(start)` with `_cmd` but note it won't pass any arugments

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should kick off NSURLConnection in a singleton thread like this:

```
+ (void) __attribute__((noreturn)) networkEntry:(id)__unused object
{
    do {
        @autoreleasepool
        {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
            NSLog(@"exit worker thread runloop");
        }
    } while (YES);
}

+ (NSThread *)networkThread
{
    static NSThread *_networkThread = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;

    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _networkThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(networkEntry:) object:nil];
        [_networkThread start];
    });

    return _networkThread;
}

- (void)start
{
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:self.URL
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed
                                                        timeoutInterval:self.timeoutInterval];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

    self.connection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                     delegate:self
                                             startImmediately:NO];
    [self.connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [self.connection start];
}
```

An example is on [github](https://github.com/hrchen/ExamplesForBlog). Another good example is AFNetworking, it use the same method.